# C# copying from params argument to array of a specific length

Tags: c#

I'm using a factory to hide a constructor to which I want to pass an array of a known length.  I'd like to make the factory method general enough that it will handle input from a client that includes any number of parameters (too few, too many, or just the right number).

Is there a way that uses more idiomatic C# to clamp down on a params argument passed to a factory method, so I can be sure it has the right length for my created object?

```cs
using System.Linq;

public class GridFactory
{
    public IGrid Create2DGrid(params bool[] inputWrappingRules)
    {
        // Yikes!  This works, but it's kind of a monster:
        var gridWrappingRules = new bool[2];
        inputWrappingRules.Take(2).ToArray().CopyTo(gridWrappingRules, 0);

        // These are susceptible to errors:
        // var gridWrappingRules = new bool[2];
        // System.Array.Copy(inputWrappingRules, gridWrappingRules, 2);
        // --or--
        // var gridWrappingRules = new System.ArraySegment<bool>(inputWrappingRules, 0, 2).Array;

        return new TwoDGrid(gridWrappingRules);
    }
}

public class TwoDGrid : IGrid
{
    private bool[] _wraps;

    internal TwoDGrid(bool[] wraps)
    {
        _wraps = wraps;
    }

    // I want to use _wraps[0] and _wraps[1] in my methods here...
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gridFactory = new GridFactory();
        var grid1 = gridFactory.Create2DGrid();
        var grid2 = gridFactory.Create2DGrid(true);
        var grid3 = gridFactory.Create2DGrid(false, true);
        var grid4 = gridFactory.Create2DGrid(false, true, true);
        /*
         *So, then,
         *  grid[1]._wraps is { false, false },
         *  grid[2]._wraps is { true, false },
         *  grid[3]._wraps is { false, true }, and
         *  grid[4]._wraps is { false, true }.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at compile time unless maybe `CodeContracts` can validate the length. At run time you could do a check in the constructor (or factory) and throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the number of items in the array is not expected.

Comment: I can´t see why you should allow a client to pass less or more params  than if you already know the "correct" size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using value types for the array, you can create another array of the fixed size you want and just copy elements.

```
// outputCount is an int with the number of elements you want to pass down.
var outputArray = new bool[outputCount];
Array.Copy(inputArray, outputArray, Math.Min(inputArray.Length, outputCount));

// pass down outputArray here.
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to pass a calculated `length` parameter to `Array.Copy()`, and this does exactly what I want, succinctly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because `params` was specifically designed to allow the caller to pass any number of parameters.

Avoid `params` if you need a fixed number of parameters.

```
// Fixed at 2 parameters
public IGrid Create2DGrid(bool rule1, bool rule2)
{
    if (twoParamsOk)
    {
        Create2DGrid(new [] { rule1, rule2 });
    }
}

// Fixed at 3 parameters
public IGrid Create2DGrid(bool rule1, bool rule2, bool rule3)
{
    if (threeParamsOk)
    {
        Create2DGrid(new [] { rule1, rule2, rule3 });
    }
}

private IGrid Create2Grid(bool[] rules)
{
    if (rules.Length != 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("need 2 rules);
}
```